# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState'); and ı cant use react flag select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')**

```
   import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import ReactFlagsSelect from 'react-flags-select';
import { FaFacebook } from 'react-icons/fa';


export default function Slide() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('TR');
    const settings = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    const flags = {
        US: '+1',
        GB: '+5',
        FR: '+70',
        DE: '+30',
        IT: '+11',
        TR: '+90',
    }
.
.
.
.
<div className="flex gap-x-3">
    <ReactFlagsSelect
       countries={Object.keys(flags)}
       customLabels={flags}
       selected={selected}
      onSelect={code => setSelected(code)}
                            />
```

**and same problem occurs with react-select-flag, i just want to use react select flag with npm???**

Comment: your code work, please so full code

Comment: what is the code that you are passing to setstate? kindly provide more info

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { useState } from 'react'; import React from 'react'; import
    Slider from "react-slick"; import ReactFlagsSelect from
    'react-flags-select'; import { FaFacebook } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function Slide() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('TR');
    const settings = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    const flags = {
        US: '+1',
        GB: '+5',
        FR: '+70',
        DE: '+30',
        IT: '+11',
        TR: '+90',
    }

    return (
        <div className="relative h-[400px] before:bg-gradient-to-r before:from-main-purple before:to-transparent before:absolute before:inset-0 before:w-full before:h-full before:z-10">
            <Slider {...settings}>
                <div>
                    <img className="w-full h-[400px] object-cover" src="https://getir.com/_next/static/images/getir-mainpage-1-757eca6a46304def60cabce74d3f20a2.jpg" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img className="w-full h-[400px] object-cover" src="https://getir.com/_next/static/images/getir-mainpage-2-7c23764275cdaf14d7b6cf15ebbdd0c1.jpg" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img className="w-full h-[400px] object-cover" src="https://getir.com/_next/static/images/getir-mainpage-3-ffd1e98c5da51809f9adcc3a4a37d751.jpg" alt="logo" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img className="w-full h-[400px] object-cover" src="https://getir.com/_next/static/images/getir-mainpage-4-1751ad2d8fb42a88742d6751938da7e7.jpg" alt="logo" />
                </div>
            </Slider>
            <div className="container flex justify-between items-center absolute top-0 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 h-full z-20 ">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://getir.com/_next/static/images/bimutluluk-b3a7fcb14fc9a9c09b60d7dc9b1b8fd6.svg" alt="logo" />
                    <h3 className="mt-8  text-3xl text-white font-semibold">
                        Dakikalar içinde <br /> kapınızda
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="w-[300px] rounded-lg p-7 bg-gray-50">
                    <h4 className="text-second-purple text-center font-semibold font-size-16"> Giriş yap veya kayıt ol </h4>
                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-3">
                        <div className="flex gap-x-3">
                            <ReactFlagsSelect
                                countries={Object.keys(flags)}
                                customLabels={flags}
                                selected={selected}
                                onSelect={code => setSelected(code)}
                            />
                                <label className="relative flex-1 group">
                                    <input required
                                        className="h-full rounded px-4 pt-2 hover:border-purple-700 focus:border-purple-700 transition-colors outline-none text-sm w-full border-2 border-gray-200 peer" />
                                    <span
                                        className="absolute top-0 left-0 h-full flex items-center px-4 text-sm text-gray-500 transition-all group-focus-within:h-7 group-focus-within:text-xs group-focus-within:text-purple-600 peer-valid:h-7 peer-valid:text-xs peer-valid:text-purple-600">
                                        
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <button className="h-12 rounded-lg transition-colors bg-yellow-300 text-purple-700 text-sm font-semibold hover:bg-purple-700 hover:text-yellow-300">
                                
                            </button>
                            <div className="h-[1px] bg-gray-100"></div>
                            <button className="h-12 flex items-center rounded-lg px-4 transition-colors bg-blue-700 bg-opacity-10 text-blue-900 text-sm font-semibold hover:bg-blue-900 hover:text-white">
                                <FaFacebook size={26} className="justify-self-start" />
                                <span className="mx-auto">
                                    
                                </span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD0AP.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't look like an answer to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).